# Pasting an email's HTML as rich text into gmail removes style tags

Tags: javascript, html, email, gmail, media-queries

I'm trying to paste an entire HTML snippet directly into an email client through the clipboard as rich text (type: "text/html).
I'm copying the HTML through JavaScript as so:

```
function copyToClipboard(html) {
      function listener(e) {
           e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", html);
           e.preventDefault();
      }

      document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
      document.execCommand("copy");
      document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
}
```

My HTML contains a  tag which only contains media queries, all other styles are inlined. When I paste the HTML into gmail (or any email client for that matter), the  tag is nowhere to be seen.

I've tried:

1. Placing the  tag in the  tag
2. Placing the  tag at the start of the  tag
3. Placing the  tag at the end of the  tag
4. Only pasting the contents of the  tag

Here's some example HTML that's passed to the above function:

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <style type="text/css">
      @media screen and (max-width: 500px){.responsive-table .responsive-cell{width:100% !important;display:block;}}
      @media screen and (max-width: 500px){.responsive-table{min-height:50px !important;}}
      @media screen and (max-width: 500px){.content-container{width:100% !important;}}
      @media screen and (max-width: 500px){.media-type{width:100% !important;}}    
   </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0 !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; width: 100% !important;" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1062.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
   <table data-is-wrapper="1" data-type="wrapper" cellspacing="0" id="ij5t" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #FAFAFA; height: 100%; width: 100%;" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#FAFAFA">
      <tbody data-is-tbody="1" data-type="tbody" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
         <tr data-is-row="1" data-type="row" id="if2m" style="box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%;">
            <td data-is-wrapper-cell="1" data-type="wrapper-cell" cellspacing="0" id="it3i" style="box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%;" height="100%">
               <table data-is-content="1" data-type="content" class="content-container" cellspacing="0" id="ixol" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #d2edf2; border-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 100%; min-width: min(600px, 100%); min-height: 100%; max-width: max(800px, 100%); max-height: none; vertical-align: top; width: 80%;" width="80%" height="100%" bgcolor="#d2edf2" valign="top">
                  <tbody data-is-tbody="1" data-type="tbody" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                     <tr data-is-row="1" data-type="row" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                        <td data-type="content-container" data-is-content-container="1" id="ijji" style="box-sizing: border-box; background: none; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: none; vertical-align: top;" width="100%" height="100%" valign="top">
                           <table data-is-table="1" data-type="table" cellspacing="1" id="id5h" style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px; margin: 0px; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle; height: auto; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; border-color: #000000; opacity: 100%; rows: 2; columns: 2; cell-border-width: 0px; cell-border-color: #242424; cell-border-radius: 0px; cell-background-color: #FFFFFF; cell-spacing: 1;" width="100%" valign="middle">
                              <tbody>
                                 <tr data-is-row="1" data-type="row" id="is0no" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-color: #242424;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                    <td data-is-cell="1" data-type="cell" class="responsive-cell" id="ildv9" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; margin: 0px; min-width: 10px; padding: 5px; width: auto;">
                                       <p data-type="text" id="i8tvo" style="color: #242424; display: block; padding: 10px; margin: 0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; word-break: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; letter-spacing: normal; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Insert your text here</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-is-cell="1" data-type="cell" class="responsive-cell" id="i0v4x" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; margin: 0px; min-width: 10px; padding: 5px; width: auto;">
                                       <p data-type="text" id="ibme2" style="color: #242424; display: block; padding: 10px; margin: 0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; word-break: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; letter-spacing: normal; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Insert your text here</p>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr data-is-row="1" data-type="row" id="iehnz" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-color: #242424;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                    <td data-is-cell="1" data-type="cell" class="responsive-cell" id="iuuql" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; margin: 0px; min-width: 10px; padding: 5px; width: auto;">
                                       <p data-type="text" id="if5kw" style="color: #242424; display: block; padding: 10px; margin: 0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; word-break: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; letter-spacing: normal; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Insert your text here</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-is-cell="1" data-type="cell" class="responsive-cell" id="id9mf" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; margin: 0px; min-width: 10px; padding: 5px; width: auto;">
                                       <p data-type="text" id="il04k" style="color: #242424; display: block; padding: 10px; margin: 0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; word-break: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; letter-spacing: normal; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Insert your text here</p>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                           <table data-is-section="1" data-type="section" cellspacing="0" class="responsive-table" id="iyizi" style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px; margin: 0px; width: 100%; min-height: 150px; vertical-align: middle; height: auto; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; border-color: #FFFFFF; opacity: 100%;" width="100%" valign="middle">
                              <tbody>
                                 <tr data-is-row="1" data-type="row" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                    <td data-is-cell="1" data-type="cell" class="responsive-cell" id="iw7n4" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; margin: 0px; min-width: 10px; padding: 5px; width: 50%;" width="50%">
                                       <p data-type="text" id="iwrxc" style="color: #242424; display: block; padding: 10px; margin: 0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; word-break: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; letter-spacing: normal; font-size: 39px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Insert your text here</p>
                                       <p data-type="text" id="iwpk2" style="color: #242424; display: block; padding: 10px; margin: 0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; word-break: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; letter-spacing: normal; font-size: 39px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Insert your text here</p>
                                       <p data-type="text" id="iohuh" style="color: #242424; display: block; padding: 10px; margin: 0; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; word-break: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; letter-spacing: normal; font-size: 39px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Insert your text here</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-is-cell="1" data-type="cell" class="responsive-cell" id="i1sdg" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; margin: 0px; min-width: 10px; padding: 5px; width: 50%;" width="50%"><img data-is-image="1" data-type="image" id="id4ek" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615789591457-74a63395c990?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YmVhdXRpZnVsJTIwY2F0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80" width="640" height="640" class="media-type" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; --mobile-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; display: block; height: auto; border-color: #FFFFFF;"></td>
                                 </tr>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                           <a data-is-button="1" data-type="button" class="content-button" id="irgro" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #274E8C; border-radius: 30px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 15px; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; width: 30%; white-space: break-spaces; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; display: block; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Click me</a><a data-is-button="1" data-type="button" class="content-button" id="iuivh" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #274E8C; border-radius: 30px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 15px; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; width: 30%; white-space: break-spaces; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; display: block; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Click me</a><a data-is-button="1" data-type="button" class="content-button" id="ioxva" style="box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #274E8C; border-radius: 30px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 15px; font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; width: 30%; white-space: break-spaces; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; display: block; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; opacity: 100%; border-color: #FFFFFF;">Click me</a>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <style>
      @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .responsive-table .responsive-cell {
      width: 100% !important;
      display: block;
      }
      .responsive-table {
      min-height: 50px !important;
      }
      .content-container {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      .media-type {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      }
   </style>
</body>
<html>
```

Is it possible to paste  tags with media queries into the mailing client as rich text? Please let me know if it's not possible or if there's something I'm doing incorrectly.
The HTML itself is rendered fine. It's just that it's not responsive due to the missing  tag.

Comment: `document.execCommand("copy")` copies the selected elements on a page. `style` tag is metadata, it can't be shown, thus it can't be selected.